# Can I store documents and key-value pairs in the same DynamoDB instance?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

This is probably an obvious question, but I'm not seeing it in Amazon's documentation.

Can I store documents and key-value pairs in the same DynamoDB instance? Or can an instance only have one type?

I also don't see how to specify the object type when writing an item.

Answer (score 2):

The wording is confusing. The primary keys do need to be one Data type.

> DynamoDB supports many different data types for attributes **within** a
>   table. They can be categorized as follows:
>
> - Scalar Types – A scalar type can represent exactly one value. The scalar types are number, string, binary, Boolean, and null.
> - Document Types – A document type can represent a complex structure with nested attributes—such as you would find in a JSON document. The
>     document types are list and map.
> - Set Types – A set type can represent multiple scalar values. The set types are string set, number set, and binary set.
>
> When you create a table or a secondary index, **you must specify the
>   names and data types of each primary key attribute (partition key and
>   sort key). Furthermore, each primary key attribute must be defined as
>   type string, number, or binary.**
>
> DynamoDB is a NoSQL database and is schemaless. **This means that, other
>   than the primary key attributes, you don't have to define any
>   attributes or data types when you create tables.** By comparison,
>   relational databases require you to define the names and data types of
>   each column when you create a table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see a way, when creating a table, to specify the data types.

Comment: Are you creating it in the AWS CLI, SDK or in the console?

Comment: AWS SDK for Ruby and the console

Comment: table = dynamo_db.tables.create(
  "MyTable", 10, 5,
  :hash_key => { :id => :string }
)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Table.html

Comment: Thanks, but how are document items and key-value items created differently? Every example I see on AWS documentation is only about key-value items.